# Has mongodb started providing community edition with ssl support?

Tags: mongodb

Just checked the downloads page recently.
https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production

The does the mongodb company now provide ssl support (sources compiled with ssl and being dynamical linked ) for the community edition ?

Was there a policy change or announcement recently ?

Note: Early (before community release 3.2.1) the ssl support was not present (we had to compile source code with ssl ) and the binaries were statically linked.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/upgrade-cluster-to-ssl/):

> Changed in version 3.0: Most MongoDB distributions now include support
>   for TLS/SSL. See Configure mongod and mongos for TLS/SSL and TLS/SSL
>   Configuration for Clients for more information about TLS/SSL and
>   MongoDB.

I can't find an authoritative list of versions, however, all community versions running on a Mongo Enterprise supported platform will support SSL and this includes Windows, Red Hat/CentOS, Ubuntu, or Amazon Linux.

Comment: @jacob, Thanks for responding Jaco. I am trying to find out if the download from mongodb site will come with ssl prebuilt (compiled with --ssl) for community edition. Earlier to 3.2.1 you can only find this in enterprise edition. But there is a bit of confusion , in this link https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#previous  you will find that 3.0.9 does not come with the ssl prebuilt. Any ideas on whats happening here ? is it that the support was from > 3.0 and ssl built in support from 3.2.1 ?...any how  thanks a ton for the info

Comment: I think the original idea was to only provide easy access to SSL in the Enterprise edition.  However, after it was reported that 40,000 MongoDB instance are left unsecured on the web, it seems that MongoDB has re-evaluated this decision and have made SSL available in the standard installers.  You are indeed right that SSL is only included in 3.2.1 and higher, before that version you still have to compile the source yourself.